# Не билдится проект в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Выбираю сцены, нажимаю кнопку Build, выбираю путь и... всё, дальше ничего не происходит. Спустя пару секунд я слышу какой-то звук винды, вроде когда окно с чем-то появляется. (Путь без русских символов)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: - У меня не работает! - Что не работает? - Ничего не работает! - А надо что? - А надо, чтобы работало!

Answer (score 0):

После запуска процедуры `Build` в вашем проекте создаётся папка с соответсвующим названием `Build` (или если вы сами указали путь, то перейдите по нему). В ней находятся два exe файла.

Один из них - `UnityCrashHandler32.exe`. Он вам не нужен.

Запустите другой экзешник и ваша игра запустится.

А если хотите нажать `Build` и увидеть запуск программы сразу, то вместо `Build` нажмите на `Build And Run`

Comment: Проблема не в этом, да и в целом была проблема проекта, другие проекты проходили билд стабильно

Comment: @sokilo, понял.